# NPOI Excell merged region

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

Есть код для формирования Excell документа

```
        var workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        var sheet = workbook.CreateSheet("HourlySalesReportVerticalView");

        var rowNumber = 0;
        var dateRangeRow = sheet.CreateRow(rowNumber);

        dateRangeRow.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Start date:");
        dateRangeRow.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue(viewModel.Start.GetValueOrDefault().ToShortDateString());

        dateRangeRow.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue("End date:");
        dateRangeRow.CreateCell(4).SetCellValue(viewModel.End.GetValueOrDefault().ToShortDateString());
        rowNumber++;
        //empty line 
        sheet.CreateRow(rowNumber);
        rowNumber++;

        var headerRow = sheet.CreateRow(rowNumber);
        **var headerSubRow = sheet.CreateRow(rowNumber + 1);**

        var mergeCellTime = new CellRangeAddress(rowNumber, rowNumber+1, 0, 1);
        sheet.AddMergedRegion(mergeCellTime);

        var headerRowCell = headerRow.CreateCell(0);
        headerRowCell.SetCellValue("Time");

        int locationCounter = 2;
        var companyIdList = new List<int>();
        foreach (var item in reportModel.CompanyHourlySalesReportItems.OrderBy(zx => zx.CompanyName))
        {
            headerRow.CreateCell(locationCounter).SetCellValue(item.CompanyName);
            companyIdList.Add(item.CompanyId);
            sheet.AddMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(rowNumber, rowNumber, locationCounter, locationCounter + 2));
            headerSubRow.CreateCell(locationCounter).SetCellValue("Sales");
            headerSubRow.CreateCell(locationCounter + 1).SetCellValue("Labor");
            headerSubRow.CreateCell(locationCounter + 2).SetCellValue("labor %");
            locationCounter += 2;
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смержена 2 и 3 строка (нумерация с 0  начинается). На 3-й строке с 2 колонки хочу добавить 3 Cells в строку в переменной headerSubRow. Однако в документе это не отображается. Прошу  помощи